# New at action script and finding issues at my 3x3 tile puzzle game

Tags: actionscript-3

This code is for a 3x3 tile puzzle game. I'm in school designing a game for my coursework and I have tried my best but this is all I can do.

The issue I think is that I'm not sure how to make it so that when the tile next to the blank tile is clicked it will swap, but not any others if they are not next to the blank tile.

Also I haven't prepared the win sequence for when they are all in order and its not random at the start where the tiles start as I was unsure how to make it random. It also says that the issue is that it expected 2, got 1. Ihave no idea what that means.

```
var blank:Blank = new Blank();
var one:One = new One(); 
var two:Two = new Two();
var three:Three = new Three();
var four:Four = new Four();
var five:Five = new Five(); 
var six:Six = new Six();
var seven:Seven = new Seven();
var eight:Eight = new Eight();
var tile = String

function swapBlank(tile):void
{
    var m = int
    var n = int
    m = tile.x
    n = tile.y
    tile.x = blank.x
    tile.y = blank.y
    blank.x = m
    blank.y = n
}  

function swap(tile,e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (tile.x == blank.x)
    {
        if (tile.y == blank.y + 110)
        {
            swapBlank(tile);
        }
        else if (tile.y == blank.y - 110)
        {
            swapBlank(tile);
        }
    }
    else if (tile.y == blank.y)
    {
        if (tile.x == blank.x + 110)
        {
            swapBlank(tile);
        }
        else if (tile.x == blank.x - 110)
        {
            swapBlank(tile);
        }
    }

}
//expected 2, got 1//

addChild(blank);
addChild(one);
addChild(two);
addChild(three);
addChild(four);
addChild(five);
addChild(six);
addChild(seven);
addChild(eight);


three.x = 10
three.y = 10
eight.x = 120
eight.y = 10
seven.x = 230
seven.y = 10
one.x = 10
one.y = 120
four.x = 120
four.y = 120
six.x = 230
six.y = 120
two.x = 10
two.y = 230
five.x = 120
five.y = 230
blank.x = 230
blank.y = 230

one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
three.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swap);
four.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
five.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
six.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
seven.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
eight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get on your swap function call is because Event Listeners always have only one parameter: the Event. So swap() should look like
`function swap(event:MouseEvent):void`.

The event will have a reference to the tile that was clicked so you can get it roughly like this:

```
tile = event.target;
```

Then you can check if tile is next to the blank one, and the rest.
But Stack Overflow is not meant to tell you how to do your assignments so that one is for you to solve.

Comment: Its not really for my assignments, i had to design the basics of a game but i wanted to finish it in my personal time so that i had i better understanding